# Datatables JQuery Adding new row - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

HTML :

```
        <div class="datatable-header">
             <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="float-right btn btn-info">Add</button>
         </div>

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table datatable-basic table-striped table-hover table-bordered"
                   data-data-url="<?= $this->url('bla/blabla/ajax', ['action' => 'list']) ?>
                   id="text-dataTable"
            >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Text</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                 </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 const textTable = $('#text-dataTable');
        const textDataTable = textTable.DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 75, -1], [10, 25, 50, 75, "All"]],
            "dom": '<"top"fBr><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"bottom mt-2"ilp>',
            "lengthChange": true,
            "pageLength": 25,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "searching": false,
            "order": [[0, 'asc']],
            "ajax": {
                "url": textTable.data('data-url'),
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                { targets: [1], className: "text-center"},
            ],
            "columns": [
                { data: "text", "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<textarea style="width: 100%"  contenteditable id="text" class="update" data-id="'+full.id+'" data-column="text">' + data + '</textarea>';
                    }
                },
                { data: "textId", "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        let $html =  '<a class="btn bg-success m-1 update" data-id="'+data+'"><i class="icon-floppy-disk"></i> Update</a>';
                         $html +=  '<a class="btn bg-danger m-1 remove" data-id="'+data+'"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';
                         $html +=  '<a class="btn bg-grey m-1 reset" data-id="'+data+'"><i class="icon-reset"></i> Reset</a>';
                         return $html;
                    }
                },
            ],
            "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty('rowClass')) {
                    $(row).attr('class', data.rowClass);
                }

                $('td:last', row).attr('class', 'text-center');
                }
        });

        $('#add').click(function(){
            const addedRow = textDataTable.row.add(
                {
                    "text": "aa",
                    "textId": "bb",
                }
           );
            textDataTable.draw( false );
            const addedRowNode = addedRow.node();
            $(addedRowNode).addClass('highlight');
        });
```

Result: 
it's updating the text for the first column and the data-id of the second column, my goal is to add a new empty row, which means i want the first column to have 'aa' and the second column to have 'bb' instead of the buttons. I tried hundreds of things in vain.

See Screenshot:

[image]

Second Thing I tried: which is a problem because if the user adds multiple rows at the same time and click insert one by one, it will always insert the value of the first new row added, since it's getting the value by id. And all the new rows have the same ID.

```
      $('#add').click(function(){

            let html = '<tr>';
            html += '<td><textarea contenteditable id="new-row-text">aa</textarea></td>';
            html += '<td><a class="btn bg-grey m-1 insert"><i class="icon-plus22"></i> Insert</a></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $('#text-dataTable tbody').prepend(html);
        });

        textDataTable.on('click', 'a.insert', function(){

            swal.fire({
                title: 'Are You Sure?',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
                reverseButtons: true,
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: function (data) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        $.post(
                            textDataTable.data('insert-url'),
                            {
                                text: $('#new-row-text').val()
                            },
                            (function data($data) {
                                resolve()
                            }),
                            'json'

                        ).fail((function(xhr, status, error) {
                            swal.fire('Error', xhr.responseJSON.error, 'error');

                        }));
                    })
                }

            }).then(result => {
                if (result.value) {
                    textDataTable.ajax.reload();
                } else {
                }
            }, (function () {

            }));

        });
```

Comment: you can use `append` instead of `add` https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @Reza I need to add a  row because I need to insert it to DB and i need to get the value of the text from the row's data because if i append html and then get the value like this: $('.new-text').val() , it will be wrong in case i add more than one new row at the same time because getting the value by id or class, will get me the value of the first row added

Comment: Unrelated to the issue: `$(row).attr('class',` should be `$(row).addClass(` (in most cases)  - in "rowCallback" you set the class then immediately overwrite it - if you used addClass it would have both (if you don't want both should be an 'else' in there)

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah unfortunately that's not the cause

Comment: Please confirm: When you add a new row (to the datatable db via .row.add) you want it to be displayed *differently* from the other rows?  Existing rows: input+buttons,  New row: input+"bb"?

Comment: @freedomn-m i want to add a row thats different from the existing rows, i want the new row to have "aa" in the Text column and "bb" in the Actions column

Comment: So what have you tried for this?  How the row is rendered is based on the `columns` definition, which you have 2 columns one with an input and one with buttons.

Comment: Your comment above about inserting into the DB to get the values seems at odds with displaying the values in a different format.  You generally have options add directly to the HTML (problem described here solved, but there'll be other underlying issues) / you update the data in the DB and tell datatables to refresh / you handle this manually (which seems to be what you're trying).  Both of the last 2 options will need different "templates" in datatables configured.

Comment: Don't add code in comments (unless it's a few characters) - edit the question to add a block of code.

Comment: @freedomn-m I've already shared in the question what I've tried to add an empty new row. 


my plan is every time the user clicks Add button , a new row will be inserted where the user can edit the text area and in the second column i intend to add a new button named insert where onclick it will save the text in the db. I only have a problem inserting a new empty row. I will edit the question and share with you what i tried with HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m i edited the question and i added what i tried as an alternative, that works but $('#new-row-text').val() will get me the value of the first row added, so if the users ads multiple new rows at the same time, it will get me the value of the first row added because its using ID

Comment: 1) you must not repeat IDs / all `id=` must have a unique value.  So if your template is `<input id="+"a"+"..` then it won't work; use a class.  2) `.val()` will only give you the first input's value.  But you've not explain how/when you want to get the value or values.   If you want to get a single value, then you select the row for the value you want and use `$(this_row).find(">input.class")` or so.  If you want all of them at the same time, then you use `$("input.class").map((i,e) => $(e).val()).toArray()` (or so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
const addedRow = textDataTable.row.add(
 {
     "text": "aa",
     "textId": "bb",
     "newRow": true
 }
```

);

Then in the render function test to see if the newRow flag exists:

```
{ data: "textId", "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
        // Return data if new row
        if (full.hasOwnProperty('newRow') {
          return data;
        }
.
.
},
```

Credit User 2Fkthorngren:  https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/61522/problem-with-adding-new-empty-row/p1?new=1

Comment: Just FYI: `if (full.hasOwnProperty('newRow')` will also be true if `.row.add({"newRow":false})`